# Stop Compilation in Code

Tags: d, assert, pragma

Is there some sort of Pragma which stops the compilation because for example an error occured? I know about `pragma(msg, ...)` but that only prints an error, and not actually stops compilation.

The reason I want this is because in certain cases a lot of errors get generated that don't really make sense so I would like to 'override' those errors by putting my own clear message in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
static assert(false, "Your Message")
```

Will cause compilation to halt.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `static assert` to stop compilation. Example:

```
version(Windows)
    static assert(false, "Windows is not supported");
```